# How to make WebAudio analyser not to freeze when audio stops

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm using WebAudio API to play and visualise sound and my code is based on [this example](http://webaudioapi.com/samples/visualizer/). The problem with it is when you pause the sound the analyser does not update. If you `getByteFrequencyData` you can see that it returns non-zero values even though there's no sound present. I want analyser keep updating data when the audio is paused just like any real life visualiser would do.

I know it's not the issue when you use `<audio>` element + `createMediaElementSource` instead of `createBufferSource` but the last has better browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Simply continue to call `requestAnimationFrame` for your draw loop, and keep drawing using the data from the `AnalyserNode`.

The bit of code that makes this demo "freeze" is this:

```
if (this.isPlaying) {
  requestAnimFrame(this.draw.bind(this));
}
```

If you drop the `if(`, it's work as you want.

Comment: Already done this. Does not help. AnalyzerNode gives "frozen" non-zero values.